# Remind: How to set reminder every 3 months

Tags: remind

I'm trying to use Remind to set a reminder every 3 months, and I'm not sure how to do this based on reading through the man page. I've tried something like this:

```
REM 24 Jan Apr Jul Oct MSG My reminder
```

I would expect this to do the 24th day of January, April, July, and October (every 3 months), but instead, it throws the error "Month specified twice". Seems Remind does not like specifying multiple months. Anyone know another method for setting it to remind every 3 months?

Answer (score 1):

[remind](https://linux.die.net/man/1/remind) knows about days, weekdays, months and years so every month is possible, but every 2 weeks or 3 months needs multiple statements:

```
REM 24 Jan MSG My reminder
REM 24 Apr MSG My reminder
REM 24 Jul MSG My reminder
REM 24 Oct MSG My reminder
```

If you do that once and don't mention the year, you have what you need *until forever*

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to think of "three calendar months", you could just specify a start date and a 90 days repeat interval:

```
REM 2018-11-15 *90 MSG Another 90 days have passed
```

Answer (score 1):

From the man page:

> Suppose you want to be reminded of something on the 15th of January, April, July, and October. You could make four separate reminders, or you could use:
>
> ```
> REM 15 SATISFY [isany($Tm, 1, 4, 7, 10)] MSG 15th Reminder!
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This "succinctly" gives the reminder in the original question:

```
REM 24 SATISFY [(monnum(trigdate()) -1 ) % 3 == 0]
IF trigvalid()
    REM [trigdate()] MSG test 3 month
ENDIF
```

Here's my understanding of the logic, but it may not be perfect. `REM 24` triggers a reminder on the 24th of every month. Then `SATISFY` checks if the condition in square brackets is true. 'trigdate()' is the date we are on and `monnum()` returns the current month number from the triggered date. Subtract 1 from the returned *monthnum*, divide by 3, and see if the remainder is 0 (modulo operator %). If it is true, go on. `remind` then enters if the `IF` (which may not be necessary, but I was following an example on the man page) and gets to the actual reminder.